# Memory "initialization" on HP ProLiant servers

Tags: memory, hp-proliant

I noticed recently that when I am looking at the iLO Console for my HP ProLiant servers that when they start up there is a report of total memory installed (say 32768 MB), and then there is a process running on that memory to "initialize".

This process takes a lot longer than the "RAM check" on desktops (and not linearly longer, either - 32GB of memory *should* take ~8x longer to 'check' as 4GB on a desktop, yet the "initializing" period is more along the lines of 12-55x longer, and the server has beefier CPUs).

I'm curious: What is this process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is doing a more complete initialization than the desktop. Servers are designed differently than Desktops, especially in systems with more than one populated CPU socket. Adding in NUMA gets you an even bigger difference. Those differences result in increased time. HP touches on this in an advisory surrounding the same 32GB memory initialization time you mention:

http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?locale=en_US&objectID=c00776039

> Depending on the number of DIMMs installed in the server and the type of server, delays of up to several minutes before the HP ProLiant logo appears on the monitor may be observed. This is normal and expected behavior.

Comment: I figured it was likely "normal" - but hadn't ever paid attention until recently. Thanks.